# TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I am making a Discord bot and I have a meme command that gets memes from r/memes, however sometimes it gives a meme and sometimes the code crashes and gives this error in console:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I'm not too sure what it could be so if anyone could help me out that would help a lot.

Here's my `!meme` command code:

```js
const https = require('https');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/hot/.json'

module.exports = {
    name: 'meme',
    description: 'sends meme',
    execute(message, args) {

        https.get(url, (result) => {
            var body = ''
            result.on('data', (chunk) => {
                body += chunk
            })

            result.on('end', () => {
                var response = JSON.parse(body)
                var index = response.data.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1].data

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {

                    var text = index.selftext
                    const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(subRedditName)
                        .setColor(4388341)
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send(textembed)
                }

                var image = index.preview.images[0].source.url.replace('&amp;', '&')
                var title = index.title
                var link = 'https://reddit.com' + index.permalink
                var subRedditName = index.subreddit_name_prefixed

                if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {
                    const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                        .setTitle(subRedditName)
                        .setColor(4388341)
                        .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
                        .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)

                    message.channel.send(textembed)
                }
                console.log(image);
                const imageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                    .setTitle(subRedditName)
                    .setImage(image)
                    .setColor(4388341)
                    .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})`)
                    .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`)
                message.channel.send(imageembed)
            }).on('error', function (e) {
                console.log('Got an error: ', e)
            })
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: `response.data.children[Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1].data` either response.data is undefined or children.data is undefined check for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're setting a hardcoded number (`99`) to get a random element from the `response.data.children` array. I've just checked the length of that array and it was 26. If your random number will be larger than that (and there is as you're generating a random number between 1 and 100), `response.data.children[randomNumber]` will be `undefined`.

Try to use the array's length as the max number instead so it will never be more than the number of elements:

```js
let index =
  response.data.children[
    Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.children.length)
  ].data;
```

The full code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'meme',
  description: 'sends meme',
  execute(message, args) {
    https.get(url, (result) => {
      let body = '';

      result.on('data', (chunk) => {
        body += chunk;
      });

      result
        .on('end', () => {
          const response = JSON.parse(body);
          const index =
            response.data.children[
              Math.floor(Math.random() * response.data.children.length)
            ].data;

          const image = index.preview.images[0].source.url.replace(
            '&amp;',
            '&',
          );
          const title = index.title;
          const link = 'https://reddit.com' + index.permalink;
          const subRedditName = index.subreddit_name_prefixed;

          if (index.post_hint !== 'image') {
            const text = index.selftext;
            const textembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setTitle(subRedditName)
              .setColor(4388341)
              .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})\n\n${text}`)
              .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`);

            message.channel.send(textembed);
          }

          const imageembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(subRedditName)
            .setImage(image)
            .setColor(4388341)
            .setDescription(`[${title}](${link})`)
            .setURL(`https://reddit.com/${subRedditName}`);

          message.channel.send(imageembed);
        })
        .on('error', function (e) {
          console.log('Got an error: ', e);
        });
    });
  },
};
```

Comment: Alright so I added that to the code but now I am getting, ReferenceError: response is not defined at response.data.children[

Comment: That's weird. Can you check my updated answer with my `execute` function?

Comment: I can't seem to copy that execute above, could you send it with the full code?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be working now. I'll keep you updated if anything else occurs. Thank you for your help.